# JBL Soundfly Air with multi-router AirPort Express WiFi

Tags: wifi, airport, airplay

I got my hands on a JBL Soundfly, but it shows some trouble when I connect it to my home WiFi, which consists of 2 first generation AirPort Express linked by a cable to create a shared network.

The AirPorts are set to 802.11n only (2.4 GHz).

When I stream music from my iPhone via Airplay the connection gets disrupted a lot (noticeable audio gaps).

When I attach another WiFi-Router to the network, and connect the Soundfly to that AP, it plays without problem.

Does anyone have the Soundfly running in a similar AirPort Express network and does not experience any problem?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the JBL Soundfly officially only supports `802.11b/g` according to [this document](http://de.jbl.com/tl_files/catalog//jbl/multimedia/Specsheets/Soundfly/Soundfly_AP_SS_EN.pdf) (page 3).

This leaves me wondering why it apparently worked with the `802.11n` network, or whether that was a problem with my test. But now it has been working for a few minutes without any problems.